# Prototype js - keyup event not working

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am trying to use keyup event on some text inputs using prototype js. But the event is never fired.  here is my code:

```
 document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        $$('.inputclass').each(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
            element.observe('keyup', alert("here"));
        });
    });
```

The console.log works fine and I can see the elements logged in chrome dev tools but the alert never happens.

I have a simple textarea on the page like so:

```
<textarea class="inputclass"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to wrap the `alert('here')` in a anonymous function as the `observe()` method is expecting a function passed to it not the return of `alert()` (which is `undefined`) like this.

```
function(){
    alert('here');
}
```

Secondly you can use some of the array iterators to do the same thing over all the array objects like this

```
$$('.inputclass').invoke('observe','keyup',function(){
    alert('here');
});
```